# How to suppress author in a full citation using XeLaTeX, biblatex and Biber?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biber

How can I do a full citation, but suppress only the author while keeping a complete entry in my `.bib` file and keep a full complete citation in the rest of the document and in the bibliography?

I use MiKTeX with XeLaTeX on a Windows machine with biblatex and Biber.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I'm sure there was a question like this a while ago, let me find it. (Your problem should be quite easy to solve, bear with me.)

Comment: What bibliography/citation style do you use?

Comment: I've deleted the `xetex` and `miktex` tags, since I'am pretty sure, this has nothing to do with `xe(la)tex` or `miktex`

Comment: OK, I gave up on my search to find that duplicate I promised you. Maybe someone else can locate it. In the meantime, try my solution below. It should work for almost all styles.

Comment: @moewe

I use:  

`\documentclass[11pt,paper=a5,DIV=calc,pagesize=auto,final,german]{scrartcl}`  
`\usepackage[backend=biber,style=footnote-dw,idemtracker=false,nopublisher=false,isbn=false,doi=false,maxbibnames=99]{biblatex}`

Comment: I assume my solution worked for you then? I just checked with `footnote-dw` and everything seemed fine. If something is off feel free to complain providing a bit more detail `;-)`.

Comment: Yes. It worked out in the end.

Answer (score 4):

Try

```
\DeclareCiteCommand{\nonamefullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\renewbibmacro*{author}{}%
      \renewbibmacro*{editor}{}%
      \renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{}%
      \renewbibmacro*{translator}{}%
      \renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}
```

Where we simply empty the name printing macros temporarily, so they don't do anything.

MWE

```
\documentclass[ngerman]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage[backend=biber, style=authortitle]{biblatex} 
\usepackage{filecontents}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\nonamefullcite}
  {\usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usedriver
     {\renewbibmacro*{author}{}%
      \renewbibmacro*{editor}{}%
      \renewbibmacro*{editor+others}{}%
      \renewbibmacro*{translator}{}%
      \renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{}}
     {\thefield{entrytype}}}
  {\multicitedelim}
  {\usebibmacro{postnote}}

\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib} 
\begin{document}
\nonamefullcite{sigfridsson}

\nonamefullcite{nussbaum}

\nonamefullcite{jaffe}

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: If you use this with `authoryear` and friends, you probably want something done about the `year`, one solution would be adding `\renewbibmacro*{date}{\printdate}%
      \renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
        \printtext[parens]{%
          \printfield{issue}%
          \setunit*{\addspace}%
          \printdate}%
        \newunit}` (modulo line break) after `\renewbibmacro*{translator+others}{}`.

Comment: +1. You may want to rename the macro `\halffullcite` to something like `\almostfullcite`. ("Halfful", in English, might create associations with the saying "the glass is half full"...)

Comment: @Mico Funnily enough that is exactly what went through my head after I had named the macro. I have changed the name to the slightly more descriptive `\nonamefullcite`.